# Ajax call to action 404

Tags: ajax, controller, 404

I've a trigger on my frontend that requires an action. I've started from the businessLogic template but I'm getting a 404 and can't find why.

My function

```
public function actionExampleAjax()
    {
      // Stuff
    }
```

How I call it

```
$.post('/actions/businessLogic/actionExampleAjax', data, function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // Stuff
});
```

The server response ( 404):

```
The system is unable to find the requested action "actionExampleAjax".
```

The action trigger is set to:

```
'actionTrigger' => 'actions'
```

The same approach works fine with a form submission, but I don't want to use a form in this case.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you call using Ajax shouldn't include the `action` trigger, since Craft will add this to call the correct method in your controller when it interprets the URL.

So in the example you gave, your Ajax URL should be: `/actions/businessLogic/exampleAjax`

More details can be found in the [Plugin Development docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers).

Note that if you change the `actionTrigger` in the `general.php` config file, then you will need to change the first segment of the Ajax URL to match the new value for the `actionTrigger`.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I didn't pay attention to to the 'action' prefix.